# dataframe loc return Empty dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract some data that are in a specific date range so I'm using pandas.

heres an example dataframe:

```
1/18/2021   3000000  ...                                  
1/18/2021   5000000  ...                                    
1/18/2021       900  ...                                    
1/18/2021   2000000  ...                                      
1/18/2021   2000000  ...                                      
12/13/2020  2910000  ...
```

and heres the code:

```
def date(start_time,end_time):
    col_names = ['time', 'amount', 'category', 'subcategory', 'resunit', 'relateunit','divtype','des']
    df = pd.read_csv('DATAss_notdivided.csv', skiprows=1, names=col_names)
    df = df.set_index(['time'])
    df = df.sort_index()       
    df=df.loc[start_time:end_time]
    print(df)
date('2018-10-10','2200-10-10')
```

but I get this output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [amount, category, subcategory, resunit, relateunit, divtype, des]
Index: []
```

what am I doing wrong here?
NOTE: I used different date formats as input but none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need DatetimeIndex, so instead:

```
df = pd.read_csv('DATAss_notdivided.csv', skiprows=1, names=col_names)
df = df.set_index(['time'])
```

use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('DATAss_notdivided.csv', 
                 skiprows=1, 
                 names=col_names, 
                 index_col=['time'], 
                 parse_dates=['time'])
```

Another idea if possible some datetimes are not valid:

```
df = pd.read_csv('DATAss_notdivided.csv', skiprows=1, names=col_names)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], errors='coerce')
df = df.set_index(['time'])
```

Year `2200` is valid, if need some large timestamp, because [`timestamp limitations`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) are:

```
In [93]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[93]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

All together:

```
def date(start_time,end_time):
    col_names = ['time', 'amount', 'category', 'subcategory', 'resunit', 
                 'relateunit','divtype','des']
    df = pd.read_csv('DATAss_notdivided.csv', 
                     skiprows=1, 
                     names=col_names, 
                     index_col=['time'], 
                     parse_dates=['time'])
    df = df.sort_index()       
    df=df.loc[start_time:end_time]
    print(df)
date('2018-10-10','2200-10-10')
```

Comment: While the timestamp limitations are okay for `2200` , since the function defined by the OP uses the date as a cutoff boundary, it may  not be present in his dataset and hence resulting in empty dataframe!

Comment: @SuhasMucherla - Unfortunately you are wrong.

Comment: @SuhasMucherla - You can test it, working perfectly.

Comment: Yes,If his csv file contains the time `2200-10-10`, it will work perfectly

Comment: @SuhasMucherla - hmmm, now tested and `print (df.loc['2018-10-10':'2200-10-10'])` working with sample data perfetly.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you're not using `datetimeindex`.
Also you've given end date as `2200` instead of `2020`